# Changing AngularDart Component colour

Tags: html, css, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to change a `tab-button` element colour via CSS, Upon inspection I noticed that it has class `tab-button`, and so in CSS I'm doing:

```
.tab-button {
  color: lightcoral;
}
```

but nothing seems to be changing.

I'm probably barking up completely the wrong tree as my CSS experience is exactly nil, but I'm at a loss

Edit:
app_component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link href="app_component.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <body>
        <h1 id="introHeading">
            Hello Angular!
    </h1>
    <material-tab-panel id="tabPanel">
        <material-tab label="One" id="tabOne">
            Tab One
        </material-tab>
        <material-tab label="Two">
            Tab Two
        </material-tab>
    </material-tab-panel>
    <material-checkbox class="checkboxClass" themeColor="#F08080" id="testCheckbox" label="Test" (handleClick)="checkChecked()"></material-checkbox>
    <material-button label="Click me!" id="buttonToClick"></material-button>
</body>
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [materialDirectives, MaterialCheckboxComponent],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)

class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @override
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `.dart`. and `.html` code? Or upload it to github?

Comment: @matanlurey I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to see where you are including the tab-button class to the HTML page. Is there another html page which corresponds to the class you are referring to? In order to have the class take effect you need to include class="tab-button" within the opening tag.

If you notice that this is still not working, there may be another class overriding the color which you are trying to use. You can add the important tag to make your color take precedence.

```
.tab-button {
    color: lightcoral !important;
}
```